# How export variable correctly nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose to have to file `A.js` and `B.js`:
the path of this folder is:

`A.js` is in Project/Home and `B.js` is in Project

```
Project
    Home 
      A.js
    B.js
```

Suppose the code of `B.js` is something like this:

```
var elementi={name:'hi'};

    var esporta={};

    esporta.getAllElementi = elementi;

    module.exports = esporta;
```

The code of `A.js` is :

```
var elementi=require("../B.js");
//but when I call

var variable=elementi.getAllElementi;
```

the problem is the variable is null, Anyone can help me?

Comment: for me it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code , was unable to reproduce the error.

Try replacing `B.js` with

```
var elementi={name:'hi'};

exports.getAllElementi = elementi;
```

and replace `A.js` with

```
var elementi=require(__dirname+"/../B.js");
var variable=elementi.getAllElementi;
console.log(variable);
```

If none of the above changes work , then try updating you Node js package.